# What's the most idiomatic way to do a while == nil in swift?

Tags: swift, while-loop, null, idioms

Here's a piece of code I have in a swift Tic Tac Toe Project.

```swift
var inputTuple = readPositionsFromUser()

while inputTuple == nil {
    print()
    print("Pay attention!")
    print()
    sleep(1)
    inputTuple = readPositionsFromUser()
}

let (row, col) = inputTuple!
```

`ReadPositionsFromUser()` asks the user to input row and column, and returns nil unless it can parse exactly two `Ints`, and those `Ints` are within the bounds of the Tic Tac Toe board.

I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic way of doing this, since that `!` in the last line feels kinda unecessary; if that point of the code has been reached, then I know that InputTuple is not nil, therefore using the `!` seems silly.

**EDIT:** I feel like I should clarify that this is a cross-platform, command-line app. I'm not using Cocoa or anything like that.

Comment: Basically instead of a while loop (waiting) you should use a pattern which notifies about a user input (telling).

Comment: Could you explain that a bit further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Swift compiler may well be smart enough (when optimizing a release build) to recognize that `inputTuple` cannot be nil in your last statement.

But if you want to eliminate it anyway, you can wrap the loop in a function that returns a non-optional tuple. You can even use an inline closure, like this:

```
let (row, col): (Int, Int) = {
    while true {
        if let inputTuple = readPositionsFromUser() { return inputTuple }
        print("\nPay attention!\n")
        sleep(1)
    }
}()

print("row=\(row) col=\(col)")
```

Comment: I guess I was hoping for something else...don't know what exactly, but maybe something more ingrained in the language. But thanks for the suggestion anyway, I'll accept it as the correct answer.